# What is the source of this information that mention the encounter of Ansar youth with Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam)

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, reference-request, seerah

I want to know the **source** and **authenticity** of the following text/narration:-

> In the division of the spoils captured during the Hunayn Battle
> Prophet Muhammad increased the amount given to the leaders of the
> Quraish to warm their hearts to Islam and to connect with them. The
> Ansar (residents of Medina) were upset by this and there were some who
> complained. When Sa'd b. Ubade informed the Prophet of this situation
> the Prophet called these people to his tent and said "O, Ansar! It has
> been said that you have complained of me, is this true?" The Ansar
> said "O Prophet! Our leaders would not have said words in criticism of
> you. These are the words of youth." Then Prophet Muhammad said "O
> Ansar! I find that you have gone astray. Has Allah not given us
> friendship and love? When you were few did He not increase your
> number? When you were poor did He not make you rich? The Ansar
> responded: "O Prophet, your goodness and gifts are innumerable. May
> Allah reward you!" Again Prophet Muhammad said "You say ‘When your
> tribe told lies about you we supported you. When you were distanced
> from Mecca we gave you a home. When you were in need we did not
> refrain from giving of whatever we had. When you were frightened by
> the enemy we gave you security.' This is what you say, and this is
> true. I confirm you in this." In this way the Prophet complemented the
> Ansar. The Ansar began to weep and the Prophet said: "O Ansar! I have
> faith in the sincerity of your belief. The Quraish have only just come
> to Islam. Until now they have been defeated often by Muslims in the
> battles. I have given them extra to soothe their hearts. They will go
> home with sheep and camels. You will go with the Prophet. Do you
> accept this?" The Ansar said: "O Prophet! To be close to you is more
> beneficial than this world and the things of this world. May Allah not
> remove your shadow over us." Then the Prophet said: "The Ansar are my
> friends and confidants. If all the people go one way and the Ansar go
> another, I will go with the Ansar." He lifted his hands and prayed for
> blessings for the Ansar, their children and grandchildren.**

***Where can this narration be found in the books of Sira or Hadith? What is the authenticity of this text/narration? IS THIS NARRATION AUTHENTIC?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known incident and you can find it in both books of seerah and many collections of hadith. For example in Sahih Bukhari in كتاب المغازى see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/359-366).

Comment: Thank you sister for your answer. However, the narration in my question is much lengthy and a bit different. It would have been much better if you could provide sources of the narration with exact wordings mentioned in my question. This website does mention the sources but I am not sure where the narration with exact wordings can be found:-

https://www.lastprophet.info/prophet-muhammad-addressed-the-emotions-of-the-young